# Java/Selenium Find Element by ID - Is Selenium looping over Annotations?

Tags: java, selenium, testing, gwt, automated-tests

Currently i'm developing a relative small GWT-Application and I'm testing the GUI with Selenium. Everything works fine but while I was writing my tests a question popped up in my head:

On my DummyPage I do the following:

```
public class DummyPage 
{

    @FindBy(id = ID_SEARCH_BTN)     
    private WebElement btnSearch;

    @FindBy(id = ID_CANCEL_BTN_CLEAR)   
    private WebElement btnClear;
    ...

    public DummyPage() 
    {
        eventFiringDriver = DriverFactory.getInstance().getEventFiringDriver();
        PageFactory.initElements(eventFiringDriver, this);
    }

    WebDriverWait webDriverWait = new WebDriverWait(eventFiringDriver, 20);
    wait = webDriverWait.ignoring(StaleElementReferenceException.class);
}
```

In my Application if the user clicks on a Button a custom dialogBox is shown, this DialogBox is build in the clickHandler of the Button so it doesn't exist on the page? I passed the Button on my custom DialogBox an ID to locate it on my Test Page.

My Question is if I try to find the button on the DialogBox by:

```
@FindBy(id = DIALOGBOX_YES_BTN)
private WebElement dialogBoxYesBtn;
```

Will the Object be null ?, or will the WebElement be fetched when its created ? Is Selenium looping over the `@FindBy` Annotations and tries to resolve them ?

At the moment I have a test where I click the first button and then in the same method I try to find the DialogBoxButton with its ID - its working but it would be nice if I could locale all WebElements at the top of the page Object.

Thanks in advance for any Help.

Comment: Yes, you can add it to the page object. The object will be fetched each time you perform action on it unless cached annotation used.

Comment: IMO, the idea of initializing a `PageObject` from (within) a `PageObject` may not be a great idea. As per your question, if `user clicks on a Button a custom dialogBox is shown` essentially means that the `custom dialogBox` is part of the `HTML DOM` and we should be able to handle it from the same `PageObject`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Is Selenium looping over Annotations?* answer is Yes, Selenium loop over the expected WebElement if you are performing some action over it. So in your case if you have mentioned like

```
@FindBy(id = DIALOGBOX_YES_BTN)
private WebElement dialogBoxYesBtn;
```

So when you try to use this webelement wherever in your script like

```
dialogBoxYesBtn.click();
```

The driver will first find it on the current page and then simulate the action on the WebElement. If not found obviously it will throw the exception.

Refer [this blog](http://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/page-factory-pattern-in-selenium-webdriver) for more.